# show a downloaded pdf with CGPDFDocumentRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, pdf

I have a problem and i hope someone can help me.

I download a PDF File to the DocumentDirectory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
studioPath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"] retain];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testURL.com/test.pdf"]] retain];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:studioPath];
```

that is not the whole code but i hobe you understand what I mean.

After that i will show this PDF

```
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf;
CFStringRef fullPathEscaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)studioPath, NULL, NULL,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

CFURLRef docUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, fullPathEscaped, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE);  
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(docUrl);
```

but it crash always when i use the internet url instead of the studioPath to the PDF it works but i would't download the pdf more then once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
 CFURLRef pdfURL = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:source]];
    //file ref
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) pdfURL);
```